# perspective effect itext 7

Tags: java, itext7

public class Perspective {
public static final String DEST = "./results/perspective.pdf";

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));

    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
    AffineTransform transformContent = AffineTransform.?;
            canvas.concatMatrix(transformContent);




}
```

I need to tilt a photo with text only forward as shown below(greed is images)

Original:

[image]

With perspective:

[image]

Original Pdf:
https://dropmefiles.com/cji1I

Comment: You look for an `AffineTransform` that corresponds to the desired effect. Unfortunately your effect cannot be created by an affine transform in the plane (which is the type of transform supported by PDF). You can create something similar by replacing the grid bitmap with PDF vector graphics and applying local approximations of the transform on a per letter base. Essentially @KJ in his meanwhile deleted answer was correct, though.

Comment: Where is his answer? i dont how transform svg and letters